# How to display partial HTML page in Windows 8 metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Let's say I have the following page:

```
<html>  
  <body>  
    <content1>
    </content1>  
    <content2>
    </content2>  
    <content3>
    </content3>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

I want in my Metro app to display only the part of the page contained between `<content2></content2>`. For a full page I would use a `<WebView>` and the `Navigate()` method. But I don't seem to find a way to adapt that to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to actually write any solution code I would need to know what are `Content1` and `content3`. assuming them being DIV with an ID, I can say

```
void WebView5_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        string script = @"var d=document.getElementById('content1');d.style.visibility='hidden'";
        string[] args = { script };
        string foo = WebView5.InvokeScript("eval", args);

    }`
```

Comment: @Baim That great. I wonder if there is a way to change to whole page to hidden and then to change to visible only the parts you are interested in.

Comment: That would be very easy if you can use jQuery there. e.g. if you know all these DIVs have some common CSS class you may write 
$('div[class="class1"]').each(function() {
   this.style.visibility= 'hidden';
});
or you may want to find all DIVs directly under Body